# Java Swing Issue

Tags: java, swing, look-and-feel

I've got extended a little MDI sample-programm from an older book about swing so that the UI looks like the system-UI. Here's the code

```
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class DesktopSample {

  public static void main(final String[] args) {
    Runnable runner = new Runnable() {
      public void run() {
        try {
          UIManager.setLookAndFeel(
                  UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
        }
        catch (UnsupportedLookAndFeelException e) { }
        catch (ClassNotFoundException e) { }
        catch (InstantiationException e) { }
        catch (IllegalAccessException e) { }

        String title = (args.length==0 ? "Desktop Sample" : args[0]);
        JFrame frame = new JFrame(title);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        JDesktopPane desktop = new JDesktopPane();
        JInternalFrame internalFrames[] = {
          new JInternalFrame("Can Do All", true, true, true, true),
          new JInternalFrame("Not Resizable", false, true, true, true),
          new JInternalFrame("Not Closable", true, false, true, true),
          new JInternalFrame("Not Maximizable", true, true, false, true),
          new JInternalFrame("Not Iconifiable", true, true, true, false)
        };

        InternalFrameListener internalFrameListener = new InternalFrameIconifyListener();

        int pos = 0;
        for(JInternalFrame internalFrame: internalFrames) {
          // Add to desktop
          desktop.add(internalFrame);

          // Position and size
          internalFrame.setBounds(pos*25, pos*25, 200, 100);
          pos++;

          // Add listener for iconification events
          internalFrame.addInternalFrameListener(internalFrameListener);

          JLabel label = new JLabel(internalFrame.getTitle(), JLabel.CENTER);
          internalFrame.add(label, BorderLayout.CENTER);

          // Make visible
          internalFrame.setVisible(true);
        }

        JInternalFrame palette = new JInternalFrame("Palette", true, false, true, false);
        palette.setBounds(350, 150, 100, 100);
        palette.putClientProperty("JInternalFrame.isPalette", Boolean.TRUE);
        desktop.add(palette, JDesktopPane.PALETTE_LAYER);
        palette.setVisible(true);

        desktop.setDragMode(JDesktopPane.OUTLINE_DRAG_MODE);

        frame.add(desktop, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.setSize(500, 300);
        frame.setVisible(true);
      }
    };
    EventQueue.invokeLater(runner);
  }
}
```

But with this change, the "desktop" of the MDI-window became black. How do I change this colour to the system-color?

Comment: The code that makes the look and feel looking like the system-default. People that know how to change this know which part of the code this is. And part of this people might know the answer to my question

Comment: There is a reason that the system doesn't allow you to post a lot of code. While we need code to understand what you are trying to do, we also need words that explain what you are doing. In addition, the code should only show what is relevant to your question. Here you have too much code that gets in the way of what you are asking about. Can you reduce your code to a small example which illustrates your question? See [mcve] for some tips on creating a good example.

Comment: I don't think this is much code. When I read the book, i understood the code in two minutes. And the question doesn't relate only a little part of the code. The full code here is only supplied for completeness to reproduce the effect of the black MDI-background.

Comment: Don't hide exception for a start... You could `catch(Throwable e){}` at that point... What is the "System Look and Feel" you are trying to use ?

Answer (score 0):

> But with this change, the "desktop" of the MDI-window became black.

That is the default color of a desktop pane for Windows.

See [UIManager Defaults](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/09/uimanager-defaults/) for a list of default values for each Swing component.

> How do I change this colour to the system-color?

```
desktop.setBackground( Color.RED );
```

Or from the UIManagerDefaults program you can select "System Colors" from the combo box to get a list of colors related to the system and then choose to use that property.

Comment: So my solution is:

Answer (score 0):

My guess, so this is a borderline answer..., is that the `ComponentUI` for the `JDesktopPane` don't defined a `BackgroundColor` in your system LAF (black in Windows 7), so the black color (r=0, g=0, b=0) is used by default (or is really the one chosen...)

Now for the solution, you can set the color you want with [`JComponent.setBackground(Color)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#setBackground%28java.awt.Color%29).

By the way, you should add the component to the content pane of the frame, not the frame itself :

```
frame.getContentPane().add(desktop, BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

Comment: No, I can also directly add components directly to the frame. This opportunity was given with a newer Java-version.

Comment: @BonitaMontero In that case, you set a DesktopPane so this is ok. But in general, never update the existing content pane, it works, it is accepted but you will find other problem if you add directly a JPanel in the frame for example.

Answer (score 0):

So my solution is now:

```
Color panelBackground = UIManager.getColor ( "Panel.background" );
...
desktop.setBackground( panelBackground );
```

Just don't know whether the panel background is the most appropriate color for the MDI-background.